# In-App Billing: Can we create subscription on the fly inside the app?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, in-app-billing, google-play-billing

Is it possible to create a subscription inside my app **without first creating it in the google play console**? this because the params of my subscriptions, like price, discount, duration, etc. will be directly connected to the user profile and location and there is thousands of combinations and I don't want to manually enter all of then in the google play console web interface.

to resume I just want from my app to say: create a subscription of xx USD recurring every N months, with this title blabla and this description blabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is absolutely not possible. It is always required to create the subscription in the Developer's console. Consider that otherwise Google would not be able to manage/know what subscriptions you have, and integrate them with their billing infrastructure, which is mandatory when offering in-app purchases and subscriptions.

If you need to define a price per location, then the Developer's console has a section to specify the price per country.

Comment: and off course no way to avoid the google billing system :(